# How to output SQL query results from a database in a gridview while adding in an error message in the gridview for nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select, null

I am selecting dates from a database, With a typical result of four seperate dates.
However sometime a date is missing and only returns 3 dates.Im am using C#, asp.net.

Example one:

```
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000,
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000,
2010-06-01 00:00:00.000,
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

Example 2:

```
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000,
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000,
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want it so that this result is displayed in a Database and the missing month has a message which takes up the row with a message like "No entry".

Desired:

```
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000,
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000,
No Entry,
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: How are you selecting these dates? It looks like it would be easier to do it inside the query itself...

Comment: wondering how the number of columns get reduced in your query , can you elaborate

Comment: My Query is essentially:
SELECT DISTINCT [Period_Start] FROM [database] Where [User] like 'john'

It is because it returns several dates for each user. BUt not every user has the desired amount of dates.
So if there are 3 dates but im expecting 4. I want to be able to have a row in the place of the missing row which will have a message saying "No date" or something like that.

Comment: ok in that case according to your 'desired example 2', how do you know that it is 3RD date missing, not 2ND or other?

Comment: You would know as a date is from each month. It can be any day of the moth but there must be a date from each month.
As you can see in the desired 06 is missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do a right join with a complete result set (a result set that would always contain all the dates you need) and, if the data on the left is null, replace it with the text you need.

Something like this:

select case when x.date is not null then x.date else 'No Entry' end from
myTable x right join completeTable c on x.date = c.date

Comment: Like he said, not all users have all the dates, and I doubt there is any complete results set...

Comment: That is a good answer. But would not really help in this case as the date can vary from any day of the month.
so it can be 01/01/2011 to 31/01/2011.
So I could not really just fill it in using another date as it is important the date is noted properly. Or noted if it is miissing.

Is there a way to check a date is not null withing a SQL query?

SELECT DISTINCT [date] when //[date] is not null replace with "No Entry"// FROM [database]

Is there is a way to perform that query?

Comment: I have been trying to use SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

But I dont really know how to take out all the results and then recursively search through them to find a missing date.

Comment: Are the dates just month starting dates? If so, I can assume that by "date" you mean "month". If yes: you could make a mock-table that contains 12 rows (one for each month of the year) and use that as the right table in my query. And.. this table can even be a temporary table.. :)

Comment: I have created a mock table, And have populated it with dates. But this query does not add the no entry message as desired for some reason.

Comment: Can you paste here the table structures (both tables) and the exact query that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT DISTINCT isnull([Period_Start] ,'NoEntry')) FROM [database]
```

Comment: you can't do that as the row it self would not be there in the table. It would only work when the row with date column is null